# appending content into a dymanically created iframe gets an empty iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, append

I have a jQuery snippet as below:

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  success: function(myContent) {
    .....
    $('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame">').appendTo('body').ready(function(){
      $('#myFrame').contents().find('body').append(myContent);
    });
    .....
  });
});
```

When the event is triggered at the first time, only an empty iframe displays, but if the event is triggered at the second time, content is appended into the iframe successfully. Any obvious error in this snippet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe some browsers need a short delay for it to recognize the DOM of a new iframe. Using a timeout should work:

```
$('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame">').appendTo("body").ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#myFrame').contents().find('body').append(myContent);
    },50);
});
```

Comment: Depending on a guesswork time delay is not a great solution. The other answers using `contents()` work without any delay and so would be preferable.

Comment: You really should be using post messages instead of an arbitrary delay. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame">').appendTo('body');
$('iframe').contents().find('body').html(myContent);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vbNGA/1/

Comment: Hi codefOrmer, thank you for your answer, Adam's answer fixed my problem.

Comment: @cnherald who is Adam?

Answer (score 1):

This simple code may be use for you, it works fine for me.

```
$("#iframe_id").contents().find("body").append("Contents to display in iframe");
```