# Empty iFrame load behaviour is different

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Can anyone please help me identify why this iframe behaves differently in Chrome vs Firefox?

```
$('<iframe id="iframe1"></iframe>').appendTo($('.main')).contents().find('html').html("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>This IS an iframe</h1>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ioowilly/L9uAX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or try this

```
$('<iframe id="iframe1" src="javascript:undefined;" ></iframe>').appendTo($('.main')).contents().find('body').html("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>This IS an iframe</h1>");
```

Comment: Woah... works and it's very simple! Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

That's because some navigator need some time to load iframe in DOM

Here is the patch :

```
$('<iframe id="iframe1"></iframe>').appendTo($('.main')).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
$('#iframe1').contents().find('body').append('<h1 style="text-align: center;">This IS an iframe</h1>');
    }, 50);
});
```

Based on this answer :
[appending content into a dymanically created iframe gets an empty iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530455/appending-content-into-a-dymanically-created-iframe-gets-an-empty-iframe)

Comment: This seems like a hack honestly... why 50ms?

Comment: Year it's an hack. But i just get it from other posts, and in fact not found better to make it work with FF. If you just put "ready", you've got nothing.

Comment: Seems to be an hack too, but better that mine for sure.