# Appending HTML to head of iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append html inside the `<head>` tag of an iframe I'm creating, but instead of appending to my iframe's head, my code is being appended to the head of the actual page I'm on. I have no idea why that's happening!

Here's what I've tried:

```
    $('body').append('<iframe src="/test-iframe.html" id="if"></iframe>');
    $('#if').ready(function(){
        $('head', window.frames['if'].document).append('<scr'+'ipt src=/script.js></scr'+'ipt>');
    });
```

And I also tried this:

```
    $('body').append('<iframe src="/test-iframe.html" id="if"></iframe>');
    $('#if').ready(function(){
        $('#if').contents().find('head').append('<scr'+'ipt src=/script.js></scr'+'ipt>');
    });
```

But in both cases the result ends up looking something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="/iframe-test.html">
            <html><head></head><body>test page</body></html> <!-- This is the source of the iFrame after it loaded, obviously -->
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can probably see it has indeed appended my script tag to the wrong `<head>` tag.

***How can I make it so it DOES append to the `<head>` tag inside of my iFrame?***

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530455/appending-content-into-a-dymanically-created-iframe-gets-an-empty-iframe

Comment: @Deckerz Thanks! That works. Now I have a completely different issue, though :-( I'll have to make a new question about that.

Comment: why are you concatenating your string like `'<scr'+'ipt src=/script.js></scr'+'ipt>'` out of curiosity :)

Comment: @madalinivascu That jQuery code sits directly in a `<script>` tag inside my webpage. If you don't concat `</script>` somewhere in the middle, it'll close your script tag and everything behind it will be considered plaintext!

Comment: @madalinivascu Here's more info about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write?rq=1